# Number of topologies on 3 points

Tags: general-topology

I have a computer program which tries to print all topologies on a finite set. This the output for $\{1,2,3\}$:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 1}, {}}, 
{{2}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2}, {}}, 
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 2}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 1}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 2}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2}, {}}, 
{{1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2}, {}}, 
{{2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 1}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 2}, {3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 1}, {}}, 
{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}, 
{{1, 2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}
```

They are 45 topologies.
But [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#3_points) says there are only 29 topologies on a 3 point set.
What's wrong with the output above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your sets aren't topologies. Consider
$$\tau =\left\{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{\}\right\}.$$
We have
$$
\underbrace{\{1,2\}}_{\in \tau}\cap\underbrace{\{2,3\}}_{\in\tau} = \{2\}\notin\tau.
$$